# `aws secretsmanager list-secrets` command to return secrets and filter them by tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-secrets-manager

How do I call the `aws secretsmanager list-secrets` command and filter secrets by their tags? I don't see examples of this here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/secretsmanager/list-secrets.html

Also, Amazon's docs seem to be wrong. It says `--max-items` on that page but really should be `--max-results`. Also there is no mention of how to filter on that wiki page as well.

Comment: Not clear why the docs should say `--max-results`. The option is literally `--max-items`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Original: December 2019]

You can use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), for example:

```
aws secretsmanager list-secrets \
    | jq '.SecretList[] | select((.Tags[]|select(.Key=="Name")|.Value) | test("^Production$|^Staging$"))'
```

You can also use the awscli's in-built query option, for example:

```
aws secretsmanager list-secrets \
    --query "SecretList[?Tags[?Key=='Name' && Value=='Production']]"
```

You can use boolean tests with the awscli's in-built query option, for example:

```
aws secretsmanager list-secrets \
    --query "SecretList[?Tags[?Key=='Name' && (Value=='Production' || Value='Staging')]]"
```

Here's an outline of a solution using Python and boto3:

```
from functools import partial
import boto3

def filter_tags(key, values, secret):
    for tag in secret['Tags']:
        if tag['Key'] == key and tag['Value'] in values:
            return True
    return False

sm = boto3.client('secretsmanager')

paginator = sm.get_paginator('list_secrets')

secrets_list_iterator = paginator.paginate()

filter_production = partial(filter_tags, 'Name', ['Production', 'Staging'])

for secrets in secrets_list_iterator:
    for s in filter(filter_production, secrets['SecretList']):
        print(s['Name'], s['Tags'])
```

[Updated: January 2021]

The [aws secretsmanager list-secrets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/secretsmanager/list-secrets.html) command now supports filtering via the `--filters` option. But .. I recommend that you do NOT use it unless you understand how it actually works (see below) and you would benefit from its particular implementation.

Here's an example of how to use it to filter on secrets with a name *that begins* with Production:

```
aws secretsmanager list-secrets \
    --filters Key=name,Values=Production
```

Note that you cannot do an exact match with the `--filters` option, just a 'begins with' match, so be cautious when using it. If you have secrets with names of Production and Production-Old, both will be returned. That may not be what you want so in that case use the original client-side queries described above.

Here's an example of how to use it to filter on secrets with a name that *begins with* Production or Staging:

```
aws secretsmanager list-secrets \
    --filters Key=name,Values=Production,Staging
```

Here's an example of how to use it to filter on secrets with a tag key that *begins* with stage *or* a tag value that *begins with* dev:

```
aws secretsmanager list-secrets \
    --filters Key=tag-key,Values=stage Key=tag-value,Values=dev
```

Note: the `--filters` option implements logical OR, not logical AND.

Here's a boto3 example, filtering on tag keys that *begin with* Name *or* tag values that *begin with* Production or Staging:

```
import boto3
sm = boto3.client('secretsmanager')

res = sm.list_secrets(Filters=[
    { 'Key': 'tag-key', 'Values': ['Name'] },
    { 'Key': 'tag-value', 'Values': ['Production', 'Staging'] },
])

for secret in res['SecretList']:
    print(secret['Name'], secret['Tags'])
```

Comment: is there a way to automatically page through all results without having to do a bash for loop? I want this to be a one liner I can pipe to xargs. I can set max-results high but it still only pages out a few at a time- looks like 58 items for me

Comment: The max value for `--max-items` is 100 so I'd start with that. You're going to have to handle pagination tokens above 100 items. Or you could write this quite simply in a Python script using boto3 which has available paginator function and have it yield all results.

Comment: maybe i only have 58 items and im being dumb. One last question, can you query multiple fields with --query? So I can return items tagged with a certain tag but also items whoes name starts with `myItem*`?

Comment: sounds like I need to use python if there is no way to have the cli autopage. Also, I do have a lot more than 58 items. looks like another limitation of the cli is that query only filters _after_ items are retrieved? so it doesnt help me get around the paging issue

Comment: Right, there's no server-side filtering with this API so it doesn't matter which client you use (for example the awscli or a custom Python/boto3 script), they'll all have to filter client-side. Should be straightforward in Python. Have updated answer to include example of boolean test.

Comment: Having no server side filtering seems like a pretty major oversight. Filtering in python is simple enough, but it just feels so... wasteful.

Comment: @mcouthon actually, it looks like `list-secrets` does now support filtering natively using the `—filters` option, which allows you to filter on name, description, and tags.

Comment: @mcouthon have added examples of filtering on name and on tag.

Comment: Thanks @jarmod. I see it only works in the CLI, right? No boto3 support for server side filtering?

Comment: @mcouthon it does seem to be supported via `Filters` in the current boto3 version.

Comment: Oh man, you're right! I was using an old boto3 version 

Comment: Has anybody worked out how to use Filters so you can wildcard or regex to only names that end in / start with a string ?  Even though `list-values` does not return the actual secret, I hate getting ALL secret names, descriptions, ARNs out of AWS

Comment: Your second and third suggestions are not correct. 2 does not filter for stage=dev. It filters for a key of stage with any value and any key with a value of dev. So you could have 2 tags "stage: notdev & next-stage: dev" and that would match the filter.

Comment: @MaxAllan thanks for the more robust test. It looks like you are correct. I'll re-test and update the answer shortly. Looks like multiple `--filter` options to the awscli are combined with OR, not AND.