# Using regular expression to filter secrets using aws cli

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-secrets-manager

I have existing secrets in secretmanager which has been sandwiched between a fixed string and environment. These were created as part of Event Bridge Api Destination Connection which were already removed. For e.g., `events!connection\MyPrefix-`{Guid}-`dev`. I would like to use regular expression to filter out all the existing secrets with suffix `dev`. I see that I can use the prefix. But I am getting values from `qa` and `uat` environments. I want secrets only with the suffix `dev`. Any suggestions?

I tried `aws secretsmanager list-secrets --filter Key="name",Values="^events!connection/\MyPrefix-?[a-zA-Z0-9 :_@\/\+\=\.\-\!]*-dev$"` and it is giving me below error.

```
Error parsing parameter '--filters': Expected: ',', received: ']' for input:
Key=name,Values=^events!connection/\MyPrefix-?[a-zA-Z0-9 :_@\/\+\=\.\-\!]*-dev$
```

Any helps are appreciated!

Comment: Whoever downvoted, care to explain why there is a downvote? Let me know if the question is not clearer. The regular expression I used above is valid and is working in https://regex101.com/. Hence reached out for help

Comment: You have a lot of escapes in your regex. Have you tries this `^events!connection\\MyPrefix-?[a-zA-Z0-9 !+\--/:=@_]*-dev$` or this `"^events!connection\\\\MyPrefix-?[a-zA-Z0-9 !+\\--/:=@_]*-dev$"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you can't use the regex in filter **Values**, see this [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/apireference/API_Filter.html).

These are the only allowed characters for your input: `^\!?[a-zA-Z0-9 :_@\/\+\=\.\-\!]*$`.

It means that this is a regex for **checking your input**, not for finding values.
As far as you use any not allowed symbols like `^` in your value it can't be parsed by the AWS.

However, there are workarounds when you can list all your secrets and filter the output by regex afterwords, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59494004/7499554)